# Delete table based on other table

Tags: sql

I have two tables, and I want to delete from table A the data there is in table B, how do i do this please?

Comment: why -2 please help me

Comment: What SQL dialect / database do you use? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, this website is not a free code giver. You have to supply what you have tried, and we will help you out.

Second, you need to clarify what you want exactly... in your question you tagged multiple SQL languages.

To perform this, you can use two of many techniques: - correlated sub queries and inner joins.

**Correlated Sub Queries**

```
DELETE FROM tableA WHERE EXISTS (SELECT field FROM tableB WHERE tableB .field = tableA.field )
```

This works for SQL SERVER (T-SQL) and I believe also MySQL.

**INNER JOINS** - Most effective in my opinion

```
DELETE a 
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
ON a.fieldA = b.fieldA
```

Again, works for SQL Server, and I believe also for MySQL

Some further research from your own would definitely give you much more detailed information.

Comment: Thank you but what is correlated sub query

Comment: @AliceSmith Again, google is your ultimate friend here! https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Delete from TAble A WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 from TABLE B WHERE B.ID=A.id)
```

Comment: hi thanks can you explain for my homework ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that you can use JOINs in your DELETE statements?

```
delete a
from TableA a
inner join TableB b on (a.id=b.id)
```

Comment: how do you do this explain plese